# Changing the UILabel in a view I'm pushing to, from a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a tableview called "FirstViewController", and when I select either cell in the table, it will push to "SecondViewController". SecondViewController has a UILabel named "randomTitle", that I need to change based on the selected cell on FirstViewController.

So if the selected cell is named "a random row", I need to change the UILabel to that.

I tried this so far without much luck. This goes in the FirstViewController:

```
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
secondView.randomTitle.text = @"Test"; // hardcoding it for now

[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

But the label does not change. What am I missing? The nib is properly connected. This is what the SecondViewController's .h looks like:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
    UILabel *randomTitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *randomTitle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congrats, you have just run into something which leads to such freaking bugs, and this something is called "you can call any methods on nil with no problem".

When you set the text to your label, it is not set into outlet yet (as controller didn't start to load its view; it would do right after you push it).

To keep your code clean and maintenable I would suggest creating a property to hold the text (or, better, the model associated with the selected row) and use it in viewWillAppear of the second controller to configure its presentation.

P.S. To prove me right just put text assigning after the push :)

Comment: You totally right. Thank you so much. I'll create a property to hold the text.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your label hasn't been properly initialised by the time you wish to set its text property. Add the following code to your SecondViewController's `init` method:

```
randomTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

Assuming it's hooked up properly in IB, the randomTitle label will take on all the properties you set in IB. In any case, you need to explicitly `alloc-init` the label before you can set its text, as you are doing in the FirstViewController method.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I know how this works using storyboards/segues, but as for pushing views without segues, the following should work for the Second View Controller, but some adjustments must be made for the First View Controller

Use the `(nonatomic, copy)` property for `NSString`.

In the `.h` file of your Second View Controller, create an `NSString` to act as a "transfer string"

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *transferString;
```

In your `.m` file of your Second View Controller, synthesize and deallocate, etc. and in your viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    randomTitle.text = transferString;
}
```

This displays the specific text you want based on input. Now to pass the text, you need to go to your First View Controller; all of this takes place in the `.m` file. First, import the Second View Controller:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
```

And for your Segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueName"]) 
    {        
        [[segue destinationViewController] setTransferString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [yourArray objectAtIndex:yourTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row]]];
    }
}
```

Where `yourArray` is the NSArray you used to populate `yourTableView`